# Optimise a shell script / command to delete files

Tags: find, performance, rm

I'm running Magento and it doesn't clean up old session data, so I need to clean it up with a shell script / cronjob:

```
0,30 * * * * /usr/bin/find /var/www/magento/var/session -name 'sess_*' -type f -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
```

But that script takes usually some minutes to delete the old files.
I'm wondering whether I need to search for the files since in this directory are only files that start with "sess_" - but I still need to traverse those files somehow, right?

(around 50.000 files per day are created in this directory)

Comment: Swap `\;` for `-- {} +` at the end. I think it should drastically improve execution time.

Comment: @mikeserv, isn't `-delete` even better than `exec rm {} \;`?

Comment: @Sparhawk - that depends on your `find` - `-exec` is portable, `-delete` is an extension. In my opinion, anything scripted should eschew extensions when practically possible.

Comment: @mikeserv Good point. Portability is something I always forget.

Comment: -- {} + 
at the end didn't really work: Something like: I can only use {} once
-delete works good:
exec: 3 - 5 minutes
delete: 2 seconds
And the server load is drastically reduced, which I'm after.

Comment: oh. I meant swap `{} \;` for `-- {} +` sorry - I forgot to mention removing the first. Although, come to think of it, `find` always prepends `./` to all of its results, so the `--` isn't relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother exec'ing `rm` at all, find can handle it:

`0,30 * * * * /usr/bin/find /var/www/magento/var/session -name 'sess_*' -type f -mtime +1 -delete`

Comment: -delete works good: 

exec: 3 - 5 minutes 

delete: 2 seconds

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing in that directory is `sess_*` files, you can just leave out the `-name 'sess_*'`, and `find` will traverse through anyway. Test what it would match by removing the `-exec` part.

```
$ /usr/bin/find /var/www/magento/var/session -type f -mtime +1
```

Then for the cron job,

```
0,30 * * * * /usr/bin/find /var/www/magento/var/session -type f -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
```

Having said that, I'm not sure that this is where the bottleneck is, so perhaps mikeserv's [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183568/optimise-a-shell-script-command-to-delete-files#comment305850_183568) would be more helpful.

Also, you should probably use `-execdir` instead of `-exec` for security reasons; see `man find`.

Answer (score -1):

I would use perl, it is faster and more efficient for this than `find + rm`

```
0,30 * * * * cd /var/www/magento/var/session && /usr/bin/perl -e 'for(<sess_*>){((stat)[9]<(unlink))}'
```

Deleting my log directory with over 500,000 logs in it daily clears it out in under ~6 minutes.